# Test coverage for wrapper class

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

Issue with Test class. I am stuck at one point and not able to proceed further. As you can see in the screenshot I am expecting true as I am checking old record with new updated record. For some reason, wrapper object variables are not getting updated and then compareobject() method is not setting true.

Test method:

```
@isTest
private class LCsAndSpecialityPageControllerTest {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'****************I am inside*********** ');   
        Account newAccount = TestUtility.createAccount('test Account', 'Corporation', false);
        newAccount.BillingCity='Boston';
        newAccount.BillingState='MA';
        insert newAccount;

        Rubric__c newRubric = TestUtility.createRubric('test rubric', 'desc 1233', 'Core', 'Active', false);
        insert newRubric;

        Learning_Community__c newLearnComm = TestUtility.createLearningCommunity('test Learn Comm', '1', newRubric.Id, false);
        insert newLearnComm;

        Learning_Community__c newLearnComm1 = TestUtility.createLearningCommunity('test1 Learn Comm', '1', newRubric.Id, false);
        insert newLearnComm1;

        Contact newContact = TestUtility.createContact('Test','John', newAccount.Id, newLearnComm.Id, 'Participant', false);
        insert newContact;

        Cohort__c newCohort = new Cohort__c();
        newCohort.Name = 'January 2017';
        newCohort.Start_Date__c = System.today();
        newCohort.End_date__c = System.today() + 20;
        insert newCohort;

        Site__c newSite= new Site__c();
        newSite.Cohort__c = newCohort.ID;
        newSite.Name = 'NY';
        newSite.Tracks__c ='Anti-Money Laundering;Investment Operations;Networking';
        newSite.Student_Capacity__c = 10;
        insert newSite;

        Engagement__c newEngage = TestUtility.createEngagement('Test Engage', 'Program Participation', newContact.Id, newLearnComm.Id, 'January 2017', 'Enrolled', false); 
        newEngage.Site__c ='NY';
        newEngage.Site_Location__c = newSite.id;
        newEngage.Track_Assignment__c = 'Anti-Money Laundering';
        //newEngage.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c='Investment Operations';
        newEngage.Status__c ='Accepted';
        newEngage.Decision_Date_of_First_Interview__c = System.Today();
        newEngage.Decision_Date_of_Forum__c = System.Today();
        insert newEngage; 

        Engagement__c newEngage1 = new Engagement__c();
        newEngage1.Site__c ='NY';
        newEngage1.Cohort__c = 'January 2017';
        newEngage1.Track_Assignment__c = 'Networking';
        newEngage1.Learning_Community__c = null;
        //newEngage1.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c='Investment Operations';
        newEngage1.Status__c ='Accepted';
        newEngage1.Decision_Date_of_First_Interview__c = System.Today();
        newEngage1.Decision_Date_of_Forum__c = System.Today();
        insert newEngage1;  

        PageReference pageRef = Page.LCsAndSpecialityPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        integer i=0;
        LCsAndSpecialityPageController assignTracksController = new LCsAndSpecialityPageController(); 

        assignTracksController.selectedCohort=newEngage.Cohort__c;
        assignTracksController.selectedSite=newSite.id;    
        assignTracksController.assignUassign='LC Assigned';
        assignTracksController.count = 0;
        assignTracksController.LcFilterOption ='';

        PageReference pageRef4 = assignTracksController.lcOptionslist();
        System.debug('assignTracksController.trackOptions***** '+assignTracksController.trackOptions);
        LCsAndSpecialityPageController.WrapperClass wrapLc = new LCsAndSpecialityPageController.WrapperClass(newEngage,assignTracksController.trackOptions,newEngage.Learning_Community__c,i,newEngage.Track_Assignment__c,newEngage.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'**************** wrapLc****TestClass '+wrapLc);
        //LCsAndSpecialityPageController.wrapList;
        assignTracksController.myWrap.put(i,wrapLc);

        PageReference pageRef2 = assignTracksController.fetchEngagements();

        //wrapLc.selected=true;
        //wrapLc.eng.Track_assignment__c=newEngage.Track_Assignment__c;
        //wrapLc.eng.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c='Investment Operations';
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'****************wrapLc*********** '+wrapLc);        
        //assignTracksController.globalselectedLC =newEngage1.Learning_Community__c;
        //assignTracksController.globalselectedTrack='Investment Operations';
        wrapLc.selectedLC = newLearnComm1.Id;
        wrapLc.specialityAssignmnet='Networking';
        assignTracksController.selectedSite = newSite.id;
        assignTracksController.siteOptionslist();
        //assignTracksController.applyGlobalchanges();
        //assignTracksController.applyGlobalchangesTrack();
         System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'****************wrapLc.specialityAssignmnet*********** '+wrapLc.specialityAssignmnet);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'****************wrapLc*********** '+wrapLc);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'****************OldEngagement*********** '+newEngage);
        //assignTracksController.compareObject(wrapLc);
        //PageReference pageRef3 = assignTracksController.updateEngagements();
        List<Engagement__c> enlist=assignTracksController.Enagements;  

        i++;
        assignTracksController.assignUassign='LC Unassigned';
        LCsAndSpecialityPageController.WrapperClass wrapLc1 = new LCsAndSpecialityPageController.WrapperClass(newEngage1,assignTracksController.trackOptions,'--Unassigned--',i,newEngage1.Track_Assignment__c,newEngage1.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c);
        wrapLc1.selectedLC = newLearnComm1.Id;
        wrapLc1.specialityAssignmnet='Anti-Money Laundering';
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'****************wrapLc1*********** '+wrapLc1);
        assignTracksController.myWrap.put(i,wrapLc1);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'****************assignTracksController.myWrap*********** '+assignTracksController.myWrap);
        PageReference pageRef5 = assignTracksController.fetchEngagements();
        try{
            PageReference pageRefU = assignTracksController.updateEngagements();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            //System.Assert(e.getMessage().contains('Please select the correct Specialty. Available Specialties for this Site are: '));        
        }
    }
```

Class:

```
     public class WrapperClass{
            public Engagement__c eng {get; set;}
            public List<SelectOption> selectedCLC{get; set;}
            public String selectedLC{get; set;}
            public integer rowcount{get;set;}
            public String specialCheck {get;set;} 
            public String secondSpecialCheck {get;set;} 
            public String specialityAssignmnet {get;set;}
            public String secondspecialityAssignmnet {get;set;}  
            public boolean errorCheck{get;set;}          
            public boolean selected{get;set;}
            public String errorMessage{get;set;}
            public WrapperClass(Engagement__c e,List<SelectOption> clc, String lc, integer r, String sSp, String ssSp ){                
                eng = e;                
                selectedCLC = clc;
                selectedLC = lc;
                rowcount = r; 
                specialityAssignmnet = sSP;
                secondspecialityAssignmnet = ssSp;              
                selected = false;
                specialCheck ='';  
                errorCheck = false;
                secondSpecialCheck =''; 
                errorMessage='';
            }
        }
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your wrapper class too

Comment: Atleast do proper way of commenting your classes, so that people can understand the logic.

Comment: @SantanuBoral: Absolutely. Once I fix this, I may have to clean it up and comment them properly.

Comment: What does it actually help if you fix all issues and then comment. Why you are expecting, people will digest your dry code and fix your problem

Comment: @SantanuBoral: I am so sorry about this. I am not sure what you have not understood. what is dry code here. Any way thanks for your support. It really hurts. Again thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. There's way too much irrelevant code here for your specific issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajay, I can't give you the exact solution as I don't know what is exactly in the Wrapper class.

Here are few things you can follow to investigate the root cause of issue.

1. Create data in the test class which can fill the wrap list here. Like `Learning_Community__c` should not be null when you create data:

   ```
               for(Engagement__c eng : Database.query(Query)){  
                   if(eng.Learning_Community__c==null){    
                       wr = new WrapperClass(eng,Lcoptions,'--Unassigned--',i,eng.Track_Assignment__c,eng.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c);       
                       //wrapList.add(new WrapperClass(eng,Lcoptions,'--Unassigned--',i,eng.Track_Assignment__c,eng.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c)); 
                       wrapList.add(wr);
                       myWrap.put(i,wr);
                       System.debug('wrapList '+wrapList); 


                   } else{   
                       wr = new WrapperClass(eng,Lcoptions,eng.Learning_Community__c,i,eng.Track_Assignment__c,eng.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c);         
                       //wrapList.add(new WrapperClass(eng,Lcoptions,eng.Learning_Community__c,i,eng.Track_Assignment__c,eng.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c));
                       wrapList.add(wr);
                       myWrap.put(i,wr);
                       System.debug('wrapList '+wr);   
                   }           
                   i++;
               }
   ```
2. This wrapper class must have data which can satisfy the following condition:

   ```
      if(wr.selectedLC != existingObj.eng.Learning_Community__c || wr.specialityAssignmnet  != existingObj.eng.Track_Assignment__c ||wr.secondspecialityAssignmnet != existingObj.eng.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c ){
   ```

You must set up `system.debug` to find out that are you getting the data which can satisfy the above condition. Make change unit you get the correct date which can enter in the condtion.

3. Uncomment all code inside catch block for example:

   ```
     try{
       //...  
     } catch(Exception e) {
           //System.Assert(e.getMessage().contains('Please select the correct Specialty. Available Specialties for this Site are: '));        
     }
   ```

You will never know if there is any exception is preventing your code to run if there are empty `catch` blocks.

Comment: @Ashwin: Thanks for your time. I found that one of the method was making wraplist null. I fixed it and now it workign fine. thanks.